# Swift: How to populate TableView data from SQLite database?

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, tableview

I can't find any link or any tutorials to populate tableView data from SQLite database, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your problem in two problems and it might be easier:

1. How to populate a table view?

   This is pretty easy you just have to know how to use the tableView delegates. Here I leave you a good tutorial: 
   https://www.codementor.io/swift/tutorial/two-basic-ways-to-populate-your-uitableview
2. Get data from a SQLite database (I guess you want to use Core Data which is the main database handler for iOS)

   In order to achieve this you have to learn how to save and retrieve data from Core Data. Here I leave you another tutorial:
   https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

After you learned these two things you will only have to populate the table view with the data that you retrieved.